# What to do after P2P-INVITATION-RECEIVED in wpa_supplicant?

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wifi-direct, p2p

I am trying to implement Wifi-display in linux. My wpa_supplicant config contains config_methods=display pbc . Some android devices is sending P2P-INVITATION-RECEIVED with unkown-Network and go-dev-addr while other device simply starts with go-negotiation. I am not sure what would be the next step once we received P2P-INVITATION-RECEIVED . I tried to send P2P_CONNECT pbc join , nothing happens with it. Started new group and tried to connect with P2P_CONNECT as well as tried INVITING to peer with P2P_CONNECT. What would be the next step after we receive P2P-INVITATION-RECEIVED . Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a MAC address in your P2P_CONNECT command. The INVITATION likely came with sa=42:4e:36:d1:f4:b6 so you can PBC_CONNECT 42:4e:36:d1:f4:b6 pbc

You can add other things like group owner intent, authentication, high throughput, ...